# Changing the current directory of ftp client

Tags: python, ftp

I have a ftp client developed with python. When I specify a file in the current directory, it is successfully uploading. I want to specify a different directory except the current directory. How could I modify this code?

```
from ftplib import FTP

ftp = FTP('')
ftp.connect("127.0.0.1", 1026)
ftp.login()
ftp.retrlines('LIST')

def uploadFile():
 filename = "f.txt" #replace with your file in your home folder
 ftp.storbinary('STOR '+filename, open(filename, 'rb'))
 print(ftp.storbinary)
 ftp.quit()
 print("filename",filename,"uploaded to server")

uploadFile()
```

Here I want to specify this directory to select files `C:\Users\User\Desktop\nnn`.

Please any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Use `os.chdir()` to change to the other directory. Or put the directory in the filename when calling `open()`.

Comment: sir i put the directory in open(). then it says ftp.storbinary('STOR '+filename, open(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\nnn', 'rb'))
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\nnn'

Comment: What's the point of `print(ftp.storbinary)`? That will just show a method object.

Comment: You're missing the filename after the directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the directory prefix in the path when calling `open()`:

```
ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + filename, open(os.path.join(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\nnn', filename), 'rb'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set filename like this way
ftp.storbinary('STOR {0}.mrss'.format("Your file name"), file)